# How to pass value in Xpath Path Expression in php

Tags: php, xpath

I have in xml as below

```
<delivery_codes>
        <postal_code>
            <pin>400103</pin>
            <pin>400104</pin>
            <pin>400105</pin>
        </postal_code>
 </delivery_codes>
```

and I want to get the input value as pincode and check pincode is exists in xml. Here the PHP code.

```
<form name="form1" action="default.php">
<table class="tableborder" align=center bgcolor="#f0f0f2">
    <tr>
  <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" colspan="2" class="heading1"><b>Check Cash On Delivery Service Availability</b></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="30">Enter Your Postal Pincode:</td>
      <td ><input type="text" name="pincode" style="width:15em;">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align=center>

    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check Availablity" class="submit"></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and default.php as follows

```
 <?php 

$Pincode =  $_GET['pincode'];
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load( 'pincodes.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);



$query = '//postal_code/pin[.="$Pincode"]';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);


if ( $entries->length )
{


  echo 'Cash on Delivery Available!!! Place your order now!!';

}
else
{

echo 'Sorry!!! Cash on Delivery Service unavailable to your area. But we can serve you when you make advance payment';
}

?>
```

Getting else part as output every time and help me how to pass value in Path Expression below. Looking forward for way to achive my task. .

```
$query = '//postal_code/pin[.="$Pincode"]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
$query = '//postal_code/pin[.="$Pincode"]';
```

To :

```
$query = '//postal_code/pin[.="'.$Pincode.'"]';
```

or

```
$query = "//postal_code/pin[.='$Pincode']";
```